# the meaning of "literary achievements“

Tags: meaning

> *The essays that Arendt selected for Illuminations primarily reflected his **literary achievement**, among them dense ruminations on Kafka, Baudelaire, Proust, Brecht, and Leskov, as well as the charming essay on book collecting. Only the last two essays, on the mechanical reproduction of artworks and the philosophy in history, give any clue to Benjaamin's more profound philosophical ambitions.*

I hesitate how to properly understand the phrase "literary achievements" in the context of the above clause. I understand it that Illuminations reflected primarily Benjamin's interest in literature which would assert the last sentence. But the standard meaning of the word "achievement" is a little bit different. So how do you understand this phrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase

> his literary achievements

Refers to the critiques and essays Walter Benjamin wrote. Without the preceding passage

> In 1968 Hannah Arendt edited Illuminations, the first collection of essays by Walter Benjamin to appear in English. At that time little was known about Benjamin outside Germany, except that he was **a talented and idiosyncratic literary critic** who had committed suicide while fleeing the Nazis in 1940.

the **he** in your excerpt might be interpreted to refer to Arendt.

Obviously Benjamin was a writer of some **renown** within Germany and the selection in *Illuminations* reflects those **achievements** as writer.

**Achievement** can be defined as

> a thing done successfully with effort, skill, or courage

and Benjamin was considered to be a skillful writer.

The final sentence gives a hint that not only was Benjamin a skilful critic, he was also a **philosophical thinker**

> from his first days to his last he was profoundly absorbed by theological questions

is mentioned later in the cited [article](http://www.nybooks.com/articles/1995/05/25/the-riddle-of-walter-benjamin/)

Answer (score 0):

The phrase *literary [achievement](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/achievement)s* means what it means in the dictionary. You should not mix it up with the last sentence of the quote that mentions his profound philosophical ambitions.

[Walter Banjamin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_Benjamin) was a literary critic and philosopher among other things and he had some achievements in both fields.

The quote means while the essays Arendt selected are mainly about his literary achievements, only two essays are about his philosophical ambitions.